# Change price after import product with another price (magento)

Tags: magento

We are having csv file for example with Euro price. And our shop accepting just $.

So if we import all the products with price in euros, so we get all prices in $.

Any solution how to convert in csv or in magento this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to convert the euro to dollar using any api.
Please check the following files related to batch upload - product import.

\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Convert\Adapter\Product.php

\app\code\core\Mage\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\Product.php